# How to convert from popen() to fork() and not duplicate process memory?

Tags: c++, pipe, exec, fork, popen

I have a multi-threaded C++03 application that presently uses `popen()` to invoke itself (same binary) and ssh (different binary) again in a new process and reads the output, however, when porting to Android NDK this is posing some issues such as not not having permissions to access `ssh`, so I'm linking in Dropbear `ssh` to my application to try and avoid that issue.  Further, my current popen solution requires that stdout and stderr be merged together into a single FD which is a bit messy and I'd like to stop doing that.

I would think the pipe code could be simplified by using `fork()` instead but wonder how to drop all of the parent's stack/memory which is not needed in the child of the fork?  Here is a snippet of the old working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <errno.h>

using std::endl;
using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

void
doPipe()
{
  // Redirect stderr to stdout with '2>&1' so that we see any error messages
  // in the pipe output.
  const string selfCmd = "/path/to/self/binary arg1 arg2 arg3 2>&1";
  FILE *fPtr = ::popen(selfCmd.c_str(), "r");
  const int bufSize = 4096;
  char buf[bufSize + 1];

  if (fPtr == NULL) {
    cerr << "Failed attempt to popen '" << selfCmd << "'." << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "Result of: '" << selfCmd << "':\n";

    while (true) {
      if (::fgets(buf, bufSize, fPtr) == NULL) {
        if (!::feof(fPtr)) {
          cerr << "Failed attempt to fgets '" << selfCmd << "'." << endl;
        }
        break;
      } else {
        cout << buf;
      }
    }

    if (pclose(fPtr) == -1) {
      if (errno != 10) {
        cerr << "Failed attempt to pclose '" << selfCmd << "'." << endl;
      }
    }

    cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

So far, this is loosely what I have done to convert to `fork()`, but fork needlessly duplicates the entire parent process memory space.  Further, it does not quite work, because the parent never sees EOF on the outFD it is reading from the `pipe()`.  Where else do I need to close the FDs for this to work?  How can I do something like `execlp()` without supplying a binary path (not easily available on Android) but instead start over with the same binary and a blank image with new args?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <errno.h>

using std::endl;
using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int
selfAction(int argc, char *argv[], int &outFD, int &errFD)
{
  pid_t childPid; // Process id used for current process.

  // fd[0] is the read end of the pipe and fd[1] is the write end of the pipe.
  int fd[2];      // Pipe for normal communication between parent/child.
  int fdErr[2];   // Pipe for error  communication between parent/child.

  // Create a pipe for IPC between child and parent.
  const int pipeResult = pipe(fd);

  if (pipeResult) {
    cerr << "selfAction normal pipe failed: " << errno << ".\n";

    return -1;
  }

  const int errorPipeResult = pipe(fdErr);

  if (errorPipeResult) {
    cerr << "selfAction error pipe failed: " << errno << ".\n";

    return -1;
  }

  // Fork - error.
  if ((childPid = fork()) < 0) {
    cerr << "selfAction fork failed: " << errno << ".\n";

    return -1;
  } else if (childPid == 0) { // Fork -> child.
    // Close read end of pipe.
    ::close(fd[0]);
    ::close(fdErr[0]);

    // Close stdout and set fd[1] to it, this way any stdout of the child is
    // piped to the parent.
    ::dup2(fd[1],    STDOUT_FILENO);
    ::dup2(fdErr[1], STDERR_FILENO);

    // Close write end of pipe.
    ::close(fd[1]);
    ::close(fdErr[1]);

    // Exit child process.
    exit(main(argc, argv));
  } else { // Fork -> parent.
    // Close write end of pipe.
    ::close(fd[1]);
    ::close(fdErr[1]);

    // Provide fd's to our caller for stdout and stderr:
    outFD = fd[0];
    errFD = fdErr[0];

    return 0;
  }
}


void
doFork()
{
  int argc = 4;
  char *argv[4] = { "/path/to/self/binary", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3" };
  int outFD = -1;
  int errFD = -1;
  int result = selfAction(argc, argv, outFD, errFD);

  if (result) {
    cerr << "Failed to execute selfAction." << endl;

    return;
  }

  FILE *outFile = fdopen(outFD, "r");
  FILE *errFile = fdopen(errFD, "r");

  const int bufSize = 4096;
  char buf[bufSize + 1];

  if (outFile == NULL) {
    cerr << "Failed attempt to open fork file." << endl;

    return;
  } else {
    cout << "Result:\n";

    while (true) {
      if (::fgets(buf, bufSize, outFile) == NULL) {
        if (!::feof(outFile)) {
          cerr << "Failed attempt to fgets." << endl;
        }
        break;
      } else {
        cout << buf;
      }
    }

    if (::close(outFD) == -1) {
      if (errno != 10) {
        cerr << "Failed attempt to close." << endl;
      }
    }

    cout << "\n";
  }

  if (errFile == NULL) {
    cerr << "Failed attempt to open fork file err." << endl;

    return;
  } else {
    cerr << "Error result:\n";

    while (true) {
      if (::fgets(buf, bufSize, errFile) == NULL) {
        if (!::feof(errFile)) {
          cerr << "Failed attempt to fgets err." << endl;
        }
        break;
      } else {
        cerr << buf;
      }
    }

    if (::close(errFD) == -1) {
      if (errno != 10) {
        cerr << "Failed attempt to close err." << endl;
      }
    }

    cerr << "\n";
  }
}
```

There are two kinds of child processes created in this fashion with different tasks in my application:

1. SSH to another machine and invoke a server that will communicate back to the parent that is acting as a client.
2. Compute a signature, delta, or merge file using rsync.

Comment: Memory space is cheap. Duplicating it is cheap. `fork` is cheap. (Perhaps you're confusing memory space with memory?) How do you think `popen` creates the new process? Your other choice is some sort of [spawn](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html), but it's hard to tell because you haven't really explained what the child is going to do. Is it going to run some other program?

Comment: If my process has allocated 500 MB of heap space and I call fork, does the child process get a copy of the parent's heap space?

Comment: You can't copy space. The child starts out with the same address map as the parent. Mapped pages are shared until either process modifies them.

Comment: So if the parent touches most pages while the child runs, then you would needlessly end up with two copies of each such page, the original (now unused in child) and the modified one in the parent.  I'd like to avoid this potential overhead if possible since the child needs very little of the parent's memory.

Comment: If you can call `exec` (or a related function) shortly after calling `fork` then you can avoid this memory contamination. You can even `exec` yourself (that is, the same executable you're currently running), with command line parameters to tell yourself to run in some particular mode.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `popen` is a very thin wrapper on top of `fork()` followed by `exec()` [and some call to `pipe` and `dup` and so on to manage the ends of a pipe] .

Second, the memory is only duplicated in form of "copy-on-write" memory - meaning that unless one of the processes writes to some page, the actual physical memory is shared between the two processes.

It does mean, of course, the OS has to create a memory map with 4-8 bytes per 4KB [in typical cases] (probably plus some internal OS data to track how many copies there are of that page and stuff - but as long as the page remains the same one as the parent process, the child page uses the parent processes internal data). Compared to everything else involved in creating a new process and loading an executable file into the new process, it's a pretty small part of the time. Since you are almost immediately doing `exec`, not much of the parent process' memory will be touched, so very little will happen there.

My advice would be that if `popen` works, keep using `popen`. If `popen` doesn't quite do what you want for some reason, then use `fork` + `exec` - but make sure you know what the reason for doing so is.